# FullCalendar error - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I am trying to shoehorn the FullCalendar into the starter ASP.NET MVC3 website as a trial and am getting the error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method". The code generating the web page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/Content/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/gcal.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>

body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    }

#calendar {
    width: 725px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>


<title>Event Calendar</title>

<link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="logindisplay">

    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

        </div> 

        <div id="menucontainer">

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/Club/EventCalendar">Event Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="pageContent">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                }
            ]
        });
    });    
</script>
<div id="calendar">
</div>

        </div>
        <div id="linkContent" >
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is failing when it runs the javascript code to create the calendar. As far as I can see, the code is as shown on many websites. Anyone any ideas what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya man.. like @pointy says.. fullCalnder needs jQuery before it can do its magic..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

<link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/Content/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/gcal.js'></script>
```

Keep all your imports on the top - order is important! Group CSS then Sctipts for example. Easier to read later

---

EDIT

Picture worth a thousand words!I got this of the mini site you made

[image][image]

It seems like it cannot find the scripts at all.!

Comment: @ppumkin Your answer displayed after I refreshed IE. I had already  submitted a reply to Pointy by then. To repeat that reply, it still doesn't work when I move everything into the `<head>` section off the Site.Master page

Comment: Using mastersite? Then the code should compelety different. i Think. is this page laoded from the master site.. or is the mastersite page?!

Comment: @ppumpkin How do you mean - "should compelety different". Can you please explain further, or give me some links to a web site.

Comment: sorry i though you meant masterpages.. this is something else.. well this should work. can you show us your site or a demo site where it does not work.. because something else could be wrong

Comment: Also - try to upgrade your jquery to 1.6.x especailly if you are using calendaer 1.5.x!

Comment: @ppumpkin No, I only have it set up on my development machine at home and I'm running it under IIS. I have a production site running but this page is not yet available on it. I am loath to publish it to that site. Let me see if I can install it on a test site.

Comment: @ppumpkin I have changed jQuery to 1.5.2 which was included in the FullCalendar .zip I downloaded. When I reran it, it failed at this point - finally{b=[d,f],c=0}}return this} - with the { highlighted. I think this is in this function - resolveWith:function(d,f) - . I will try and get a test site up.

Comment: @ppumpkin I have installed it at http://testdir1.royalleamingtonspabc.org.uk. I am expecting the calendar to be displayed on the Event Calendar tab.

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for finding that out for me (see answer). What were you using to produce those results? I don't have anything like that, so obviously I need to download it.

Comment: Well you have a choice of 3 major in-browers debugger. Using IE press F12 to reveal the debugger.Nice but not great. Then the 2 great ones are Firebug extension for Firefox and my favourite -- Chrome. Right click on the page and press 'inspect element' you can debug jscript code and see any errors with a pretty precise description and loads of information! This is the same in Safari. the are webkit based. I suggest you read up on the Chrome/Safari one! Its worth learning.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

You need to import jQuery **before** the plugin.  Put the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery up at the top of the `<head>`.

Comment: I have moved everyting to the `<Head>` section of the Site.Master. The only thing on the EventCalendar.aspx content page is the `<div id="calendar">` group and it is still failing when it executes `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({....})`.

Comment: I'll repeat: you have to put the `<script>` tag that imports jQuery **before** the `<script>` tag that imports the full calendar plugin.

Comment: Please read the comments under ppumpkins answer. You will see that I have moved all the `<script>` cpmmands into the `<head>` section of the Site.Master page.

Comment: Please read the comments under ppumpkin's answer. You will see that I have moved all the `<script>` commands into the `<head>` section of the Site.Master page. The reference to jquery-1.5.2.min.js come before the reference to fullcalendar.js which comes before the `$(document).ready(function ()` call. The code is still failing however. If this is not correct, can you please be more specific in your answer. I do not know JavaScript and therefore I am not aware of its requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is correct about the order, and to make sure you have the Jquery referenced BEFORE you reference the full calendar.  In my case, I had done that correctly, but additionally I had added a partial view in after the header.  The partial view had a reference to Jquery again, which then threw this same error on execution.

I just thought I would add this as an answer, because it had me looking for a while before I figured out what was going on (because my head section did have the correct order - just like pointy's anser suggests you should have).

Again, not trying to take anything away from the other answer that is correct.  Just adding what specifically had the error show up for me -when it seemed I had done everything correct - and still got the error.

The resolution for me was to take the jquery reference out of the partial view. (it wasn't needed because the master view already had the reference)